# How to make the user keep his previous scroll position when changing page

Tags: javascript, navigation, scroll

I would like the user to keep his scroll position each time he requests a new page of a website.
Anchors would not help as they determine a predefined position and I need to retain the user position, wherever he is on his current page.
Most likely it would involve javascript but I just don't see how to make it happen.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It seems the page itself is not well-disigned , anchors should be enough (or beter defined) , you could add a parameter to the page link but it may become a XSS vulnerability

Comment: [window.onscroll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll) + [localStorage/sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage)

Comment: @Andreas - Or perhaps cookies for older browsers..